# Use Font Awesome icons across the application in Angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, icons, angular8, font-awesome

I'm working on a quite big angular application with lazy loading modules implemented. In a lot of components, in differents modules, I use icons from font Awesome.
Actually, icon are implemented individually like in this example:

In component.ts:

`import { faChevronDown, faChevronUp, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

`public faChevronDown= faChevronDown;`

`public faChevronDown= faChevronUp;`

in component.html:

`<fa-icon class="fa-md" [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon>`

Since I'm starting to have a lot of icons, that sometimes are the same in differents components, I was wondering if there is a way to factorise this code. For example, instead of declaring a property for each icon in each component, some kind of global item where I can stock all icons I want to use and call them directly in HTML when needed.

Following  [this article of the Angular Wiki](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-angular-applications/), I find out the library.add() method that seemed to be perfect for this purpose, so I tried to implement it:

In app.module:

```
import { faChevronDown, faChevronUp} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [

    AppComponent

  ],

  imports: [

    BrowserModule,

    FontAwesomeModule

  ],

  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule {

  constructor() {

    library.add(faChevronDown, faChevronUp);

  }

}
```

and in my component.html:

`<fa-icon class="fa-md" icon="faChevronDown"></fa-icon>`

But I still have errors: in my display I don't see any Icon (the screen is displaying but where I should see Icons it's empty), and in console I have this error:

**FontAwesome: Property `icon` is required for `fa-icon`/`fa-duotone-icon` components. This warning will become a hard error in 0.6.0.**

So I need to fix it or to find another proper solution to factorise icons in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you did not `explicity` declare `faChevronDown` in the component where you are using it.

You have to have something like

```
import { faChevronDown, faChevronUp} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export class YourComponent {
 faChevronDown = faChevronDown;
 ...
}
```

Then in your HTML template

```
 <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: The point is that I didn't want to have all those import in each components, but only once in the app root module. So to have to import the icon in the component is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring the component, that uses the Font Awesome icon in its template, in the same module that imports the `FontAwesomeModule`?

Sticking to your example, your template should then look like the following:

```html
<fa-icon class="fa-md" icon="chevron-down"></fa-icon>
```

You can find the appropriate icon names that you need to use, by finding the icon over on the website of Font Awesome itself.